# Mac Excel: =CELL("filename",A1) returns "#NAME?"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel, I'm trying to get the full path to the current workbook, using:

```
=CELL("filename",A1)
```

...and Excel is putting `#NAME?` in the cell instead of the path.

I am using Excel for Office 365, the latest version. I thought maybe Mac Excel doesn't have this function, but checking the in-app Excel help I see:

[image]

...so it seems like it is supported in Mac Excel for Office 365.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. I just needed to use `=CELL("filename")`

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is a work around formula that can work on your computer and also on 365 on the Internet (such as in MS Teams).
What I did is put the following formula in B6 [example here]:
=IfErro(Cell("FileName",A2),B5)
Then, before uploading the file to MS Teams, I copied and pasted the file name given by that formula to B5.  So when it runs in MS Teams (Excel 365 on line), it reads from B5, but when it is downloaded or used on my computer, it reads from B6.

It is only a workaround, but works perfectly.